# How to initialize another folder to use git

Tags: git, github, terminal, hugo

I have a Hugo blog that uses a theme. Now I want to pull in the latest changes made to the theme I'm using but already my blog folder already has git. My question is how do I link up the theme folder to the author repo and be able to pull in the latest changes. I Hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can define another remote for your repo :

```
git remote add upstream <otherRepoURL>
```

*(*`upstream` *or anything else, be sure your repo doesn't already have one named that)*

Then to check changes there, you will be able to do `git fetch upstream` to get their latest changes, independently of `origin` or whatever name you have set for your other remote(s).

Comment: Hmm, here is the [repo](https://github.com/peoray/blog), I want the `themes/` to link to the original theme so I can pull in the latest changes. Already everything links to my own repo, does your answer also does the same thing?

Comment: If themes/ is itself a different git repository then i would suggest to go with git submodules: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: @ASR Yes, I know too few about submodules to have foreseen the need, but I had wondered. Maybe do an answer in that sense if you feel like it?

Answer (score 0):

If `themes/` is itself a different git repository then i would suggest to go with git [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules):